# Messaging mechanism between multiple backend servers

Tags: architecture, system-design

Not sure if there's a specific stackexchange portal for this question, but I am trying to understand what do people/enterprises mostly use to communicate between multiple servers asynchronously. Below is my architecture till now.

Server 1 - I have a flask server running socketIO as well as HTTP end point (testing for now, will put behind a Gunicorn). This server is responsible for maintainint client socket connections and relaying messages between client and server.

Server 2 - I have another "processing server" that is supposed to do computations based on the messages received from clients, and might or might not produce output on the back of those messages. This is another flask/http server which hosts an endpoint that the server 1 can call.

For my use-case, I want to send message from server 1 to server 2, but not wait for any response back (as server 2 might not produce any), and later if server 2 decides to produce something, I need server 1 to get that output and relay that back to the client over the socket connection.

Here are what I am thinking for now

1. I am thinking, I can somehow do an async post request call (if there is something like an async request) from server 1 to server 2, and then back from server 2 to server 1 (when/if it produces some output). When in future I have multiple server 1 and server 2, I can maybe ensure that certain clients are services by specific servers to maintain consistency.
2. Change server 2 to be socketio enabled, and then create a long standing socket connection between server 1 and server 2. Again, with scale, I need to ensure that a client is serviced by specific server so all messages go to same server.
3. I am reading about messaging queues (kafka etc.) so perhaps can use that?

I wanted to understand your take on how you'd go about designing this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, Server 1 is used for routing requests to the proper endpoint.  But the output from server 2 is what is the client is interested in.  So is it possible server 1 can replaced entirely by a load balancer?

1. This is a lot of responsibility for S1, instead of making your client wait for a request that may never come, I would make an event driven system.  So S1 can immediately return success if the message is sent to S2 correctly.  Then have some other server return the actual response to the client.
2. I think you are on the right track. To communicate between server 1 and server 2, a message queue is the usual approach. It is asynchronous because server 1 won't be waiting for a result from server 2.  A great option is RabbitMq (self hosted) or SQS (AWS cloud).
3. Why do all messages need to be routed to the same server?  Consider making your system "Stateless" - so each request from the client needs to contains all the information needed to complete the request.  This is usually implemented with a session store, so a users session data can be stored on a cache/DB; and the client sends a reference to that stored data, then the server fetches it and computes.

It would help to know who your "Client is" a frontend app, or another server?

Comment: thanks for the answer. Both server 1 and 2 are actually performing specific tasks. But server 1 doesnt need to wait for reply from server 2 before acking the client. Client is a plugin on the browser that keeps a constant connection with server 1 and sends any more requests. There is another client that is a different domain service that creates input for server 1.
Server 2 is another server that performs a different set of operations on the events generated by the different domain client, and generates outputs for the browser plugin connected by server 1.